# How to echo all XML within an element in PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a piece of XML that looks like this:

```
<root>
<element>Normal,<b>Bold</b></element>
</root>
```

How can I use PHP to echo everything within `<element>`, so that the output is "`Normal,<b>Bold</b>`"?

EDIT: Here is my code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml_file.xml');
$element = $xml->element;
echo $element[1];
?>
```

I just get "Normal".

Comment: Use SimpleXMLElement or DOMDocument to load the xml then select the node you want and save it out. If you have done this and are having trouble please post specific issues and the code you are using.

Comment: @prodigitalson I tried that, but all I get is `Normal`, not `Normal,<b>Bold</b>`.

Comment: then post that code, so we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = '<root>
<element>Normal,<b>Bold</b></element>
</root>';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo strip_tags($sxe->element->asXML());
```

You must strip tags when you match your element.

Comment: This will strip the `<b>`-tags too. Also creating the XMLElement is too much effort. A simple `echo strip_tags($xml);` outputs the very same result.